# Detect enter keypress from read in ZSH

Tags: shell, zsh

How do I detect an enter keypress in ZSH with the read built-in?  That is, how do I make the snippet below print "Got enter"

```
# Read 1 char.
read -k 1 "REPLY?$Make fooBar? [Yn]: "

if [[ "$REPLY" == '\n' ]]; then
  print "Got enter"
else
  print "Got other char: '$REPLY'"
fi
```

Context: I'm building a slightly more flexible yes-no prompter than what `read -q` in ZSH offers.

Comment: Perhaps a bit late, but `vared` is also handy in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ANSI quoting:

```
if [[ $REPLY == $'\n' ]]; then
```

`$'...'` is like single quotes, but certain escaped characters have special meaning: `\n` is a linefeed character, `\t` is a tab, `\\` is a literal backslash, `\'` is a literal single quote, etc.